# How to fix wrong Model description in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

My model description on my production environment for stock.picking model shows a wrong description value.
This is how it supposed to look like and how it looks like on my test environment
[image]

This is how it looks like on my production environment which is not supposed to be:
[image]

it shows Picking List as Model description instead of Transfer

Don't really know whats wrong and what to do and this is causing a very big issue for me, I would appreciate any help I can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to overriding of description, when i tried to replicate the reported issue i found that you may have used the description along with _inherit attribute. For example:

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'
    _description = "New Description Picking"
```

Please try it by removing the _description or updating it.